# common mark / vscode table of contents not working

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, commonmark

I'm using the current version visual studio code and extensions Markdown All in One, Markdown Paste, markdownlint, and Markdown+Math.

in markdown I write:

```
## Table of Contents

1. [heading](##heading%201)
2. [heading](##heading%202)

## heading 1

...

## Heading 2
```

This works as expected in the preview screen, which is nice but irrelevant

In Html I get

```
<h2 id="table-of-contents">Table of Contents</h2>
<ol>
<li><a href="##heading%201">heading 1</a></li>
<li><a href="##heading%202">heading 2</a></li>
</ol>
<h2 id="heading-1">heading 1</h2>
...
<h2 id="heading-2">heading 2</h2>
```

and while the links navigate to file:///c:....html#heading%20X the broswer, current version of chrome, doesn't jump to the right spot.

How can I fix this? Is it a problem with the md to html transformation or the file protocol?